# Is copying lib32 necessary on FreeBSD amd64

Tags: installation, freebsd

Is it necessary to copy lib32 during a FreeBSD amd64 installation? What are they used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lib32` contains 32-bit libraries, which are required to run any i386-targeted binary, such as `wine`.